# MySQL & Unix timestamp query

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a db table that has the following structure:
id (auto increment), title (varchar 255), datetime (datetime format)

I am trying to get all articles in the future, eg after current timestamp - would the query below look right? I have one row that has a datetime of 2012-01-19 10:02:20 so cannot understand why this isn't being shown in the results?

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) AS end_dateStamp 
FROM (`news`) WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`datetime`) > 1326991924
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) AS end_dateStamp 
FROM `news` 
WHERE `datetime` > NOW()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use mysql's [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function:

```
SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) AS end_dateStamp 
FROM (`news`) WHERE `datetime` > NOW()
```